# How to configure git repo with multiple java projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, git

I'm following this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ to get familiar with spring/REST.  However, the git repo (git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest.git) has many individual java projects each with their own gradle build.  I'd like to edit the code in Eclipse, as that's the whole point, but this hasn't proved trivial.

So far, I've created a general project for the git repo, and then separate java projects for each of the folders from the repo, linking the source in my java projects to the source/test folders in the repo.  This has worked great except that I don't have the spring jars in my dependencies for the java projects, I get a ton of errors as well as lose the nice autocomplete of function names, etc.

What is the correct way to fix this?  It seems like there isn't a good way to install the jars for spring in each java project without using maven or some other build tool, which seems redundant and inefficient since I can build the source from the repo project.  If this is the case, should I make a build for each separate project even though the idea for the tutorial is that they each come with gradle?

Thanks for your help, and please excuse the slight open endedness of it--I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: Would really appreciate any help guys.  Kind of stuck!

Comment: Ok, at this point, I've created a java project that just mirrors the one of the projects in a folder in the git repo I pulled down--works great.  I can build and everything using the build files in the git repo.  Now the only problem is that the java project doesn't have the spring dependencies, so I get errors in the editor--a minor inconvenience since I'd like the features of the IDE.  Any idea how to fix this?